# Type 'Any' has no subscript members NSIndexPath and indexPath Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have recently converted my code to `Swift 3.0` from `Swift 2`

I am getting value like this

```
let productRequestID = Int(self.array[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]["ProductRequest"]!!["product_request_id"] as! NSString as String)!
let requestTitle =   ((self.array[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]["ProductRequest"]!!["request_title"] as! NSString) as String) as String
```

Now I am getting an error **Type 'Any' has no subscript members**

Comment: You might want to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Type+%27Any%27+has+no+subscript+members) for it...

Comment: Try `self.array[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]` to `self.array[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item] as! [String:Any]`

Answer (score 0):

`self.array[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]["ProductRequest"]`  This line returns the object in `Any` so compiler unable to find the key `product_request_id` as `Any` type.

So you have to type cast into `Dictionary<Any>` then you can get your value like this:

```
let dict = self.array[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]["ProductRequest"] as? Dictionary<Any>
let productRequestID = Int(dict!["ProductRequest"]as? String ?? "")
let requestTitle = dict!["request_title"]as? String ?? ""
```